# How to replace multiple HTML elements into another type of element which is in a regular string form

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="content">Content 1</span>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <span class="content">Content 2</span>
    <b>
        <span class="content">Content 3</span>
    </b>
    <div class="content">Hello</div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to get all elements with class "content" and then replace them with another element which is currently in a string form.

So its,

```
var stringHtml = "<input type='text' />";
```

This stringHtml should replace all the class="content" and be rendered as a regular input element in place of all the class="content" elements.

Comment: So... like [jQuery's .replaceWith()](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)?

Comment: And if you don't want to use any library - then simply looping over the elements selected via `document.querySelectorAll`, and setting their `outerHTML` property to the string value, should also do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically it:

```js
var stringHtml = "<input type='text' />";

document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(elm => {
  elm.outerHTML = stringHtml;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="content">Content 1</span>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <span class="content">Content 2</span>
  <b><span class="content">Content 3</span></b>
  <div class="content">Hello</div>
</div>
```

But you probably need a name for each of the input elements, so I will suggest this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(elm => {
  var name = elm.attributes['name'].value;
  elm.outerHTML = `<input type="text" name="${name}" />`;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="content" name="input1">Content 1</span>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <span class="content" name="input2">Content 2</span>
  <b><span class="content" name="input3">Content 3</span></b>
  <div class="content" name="input4">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use "querySelectorAll" to grab all of the relevant DOM elements with the "content" class, and then change their "innerHTML".

```js
var stringHtml = "<input type='text' />";

// select all DOM element with the "content" class
var contentElements = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
  
for (var i = 0; i < contentElements.length; i++) {
  // replace the inner HTML of each element
  contentElements[i].innerHTML = stringHtml;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="content">Content 1</span>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <span class="content">Content 2</span>
    <b>
        <span class="content">Content 3</span>
    </b>
    <div class="content">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Its worth noting that you probably would want to add more details to that input html for it to be useful, but I'm just answering your exact question.
The above code is safe for browsers that do not support forEach, arrow functions, and other modern JS features (like internet explorer).